# How much ice will melt in water contained in a copper container?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition

Lets say some amount of ice is given to some amount of water in a copper container ( I will not give the exact values because you can choose them at your wish).The ice is at a temperature and the water and copper container is at some temperature. We will assume that it is separated from the out side environment. The question is what percent of ice will melt?

Now , the part that bugs me that , if I try to calculate the temperature $T$ (with calorimeter equations) that the system will settle to , then I will can get three kinds of values(depending on the initial values) :

$(1)$ $T = 0^0C$ 
$(2)$ $T < 0^0C$ 
$(3)$ $T > 0^0C$

for the $(2)$ option , all the water will turn into ice , so no ice will melt.
for the $(3)$ option , all the ice will turn into water .
for the $(1)$ option , It is not clear if the water is water or ice , because it is in a transition phase.(kind of confused with this one)

So asking the question "What percentage of ice will melt in water contained in a copper container" Is kind of weird to me, because either $0$% or $100$% of the ice will turn into water. Is there something wrong with my line of reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final temperature is 0 C it can be 100% ice, 100% water or anything in between, without knowing the initial temperatures and quantities of ice, water and copper.

Hope this helps.